# group dataframes with the same dimensions in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm looking to group data frames that have the same dimensions in a list. so for example if

```
a<- (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7)

and dim(df1) = dim (df4) = dim(df7)
and dim(df2) = dim(df3)
and dim(df5) = dim(df6)
```

how could i group like-dimensioned objects? Preferably grouping them into separate lists?

Thanks!

(The list I am working with has hundreds of data frames so this is for illustrative purpose only)

Answer (score 2):

We can keep all the datasets in a `list`.  Then loop over the `list` and `paste the`dim`together, and use that to`split`the`list`.

```
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:7))
v1 <- sapply(lst, function(x) paste(dim(x), collapse="."))
split(lst, v1)
```

Comment: Small nitpick: I would set `collapse="."` so that `c(2,12)` doesn't come out the same as `c(21,2)`

Comment: @mrip Thanks, that is a good point.  Didn't thought about that.